# How to detect if painting last frame in buffered paint animation?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using `BeginBufferedAnimation()` during WM_PAINT to animate a custom control (cross-fade).
I know when the first frame of the animation is painted; when I call `EndBufferedAnimation()` with fUpdateTarget = TRUE.
I can determine if the animation is in progress by checking the return value from `BufferedPaintRenderAnimation()`.

Question is: how do I know when the last frame of the animation is painted?

I couldn't find an API call that can do this.

One thing that comes to mind, is to use `GetTickCount()` to determine the time that elapsed since the call to `EndBufferedAnimation()` and check that against the `dwDuration` member of the `BP_ANIMATIONPARAMS` struct.
However, I'm not sure if this method is very accurate.

Is there another (foolproof) way to determine if WM_PAINT is painting the last frame of the animation?

**EDIT**

Obviously, checking the elapsed time doesn't work when the animation is prematurely stopped by a call to `BufferedPaintStopAllAnimations()` or invalidating the part of the client area that is being animated.

**EDIT 2**

This is my (simplified) WM_PAINT code:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

HDC DC = BeginPaint(Handle, &ps);

if (DC != NULL)
{
    // If animation in progress, paint the next frame.
    if (!BufferedPaintRenderAnimation(Handle, DC))
    {
        BP_ANIMATIONPARAMS ap = {sizeof(ap)};
        ap.style      = BPAS_LINEAR;
        ap.dwDuration = 1000;

        RECT R;

        GetClientRect(Handle, &R);

        HDC hdcFrom, hdcTo;

        HANIMATIONBUFFER Animation = BeginBufferedAnimation(Handle, DC, &R, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &ap, &hdcFrom, &hdcTo);

        if (Animation)
        {
            if (hdcFrom) Paint(hdcFrom, &R, OldState);
            if (hdcTo  ) Paint(hdcTo,   &R, NewState);

            // Paint the first frame.
            EndBufferedAnimation(Animation, true);
        }
        else
            Paint(DC, &R, NewState);
    }
    else
    {
        // Here, I want to check if BufferedPaintRenderAnimation() painted the last frame.
    }

    EndPaint(Handle, &ps);
}
```

**EDIT 3**

My custom control has a child control, which needs to be animated in sync with its parent. For this purpose, I'm letting the child control paint itself into the first and last animation frame by sending it a `WM_PRINT` message inside my `Paint()` method. The child control receives its `WM_PAINT` message after the parent is painted. To prevent the child control from painting while the parent is being animated, I wanted to hide the child control when I start the animation and show it again after the animation finished.

Since I couldn't find a foolproof way to detect when the animation finishes, I decided not to hide the child control. Instead, I avoid repainting the child control with `RedrawWindow(ChildHandle, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE | RDW_NOFRAME)` after the call to `EndBufferedAnimation()` and when `BufferedPaintRenderAnimation()` returns `true`. This way, 
`BufferedPaintRenderAnimation()` paints the child control in its final state when the animation finishes, so the child control doesn't have to.

Comment: Using the [animation manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uianimation/scenic-animation-api-overview) you can monitor its [statue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uianimation/ne-uianimation-ui_animation_manager_status) via [`SetManagerEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uianimation/nf-uianimation-iuianimationmanager-setmanagereventhandler). When the status turns from BUSY to IDLE, the last frame is painted.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for your reply. I think `IUIAnimationManager::GetStatus()` does the same thing. Unfortunately, this only tells me if all animations have finished. Think of the mouse cursor moving from one control to another. The first control can still be animating from 'hot' to 'normal' while the second control is animating from 'normal' to 'hot'. The status only changes to 'idle' when both animations have finished. If the mouse cursor keeps moving over controls, this can take a long time.

Comment: For multiple animations you can use [Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uianimation/storyboard-construction) which can manage multiple transitions. A transition defines how a single animation variable changes over a particular time interval.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT It looks like [`IUIAnimationStoryboard::GetStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uianimation/nf-uianimation-iuianimationstoryboard-getstatus) can produce the animation status I'm looking for. Next question is: how do I obtain the `IUIAnimationStoryboard` interface that is associated with the animation started with `BeginBufferedAnimation()`? All I have is an `HANIMATIONBUFFER` handle.

Comment: You can keep a flag that remembers what `BufferedPaintRenderAnimation` returned during the previous paint cycle. When it changes from `true` to `false`, then the buffered animation has completed.

Comment: @RaymondChen `BufferedPaintRenderAnimation()` is only called when the control is repainted, for example when the mouse cursor enters or leaves the control. Unfortunately, there could be a long time between the mouse leaving and entering again (maybe never). I need to do stuff immediately when the animation finishes.

Comment: When the animation finishes, you will get one final `WM_PAINT` message where `BufferedPaintRenderAnimation` returns false. That's your signal that the animation is over.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually, you don't get one final `WM_PAINT` message after the animation finishes. If that were the case, then the `WM_PAINT` code in my second edit would restart the animation as soon as it finished, resulting in an endlessly repeating animation, which it doesn't.  Anyway, I solved my problem (see my third edit).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT and RaymondChen Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT`IUIAnimationManager::GetStatus()` always returns `UI_ANIMATION_MANAGER_IDLE`, whether the animation is in progress or not. Also, [`IUIAnimationManager::Pause()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uianimation/nf-uianimation-iuianimationmanager-pause) doesn't pause the animation. I don't think `BeginBufferedAnimation()` uses the `IUIAnimationManager` interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution to my problem.

See EDIT 3.